# Quadratic polynomials in variables x,yx,y

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, area

I have two equations which define 2-order areas I have to determine matrix, eigenvalues, definiteness and area.

I determine first three things, but how can I find out which area is it?

**Example 1.**

$a) x_{1} ^{2}+x_{2} ^{2}-2x_{1}-x_{3}=0 $

My calculations:

*Matrix:*

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}   $

Eigenvalues:
$\lambda _{1}=1, \lambda _{2}=1 $   -> positive definit

**Example 2.**
$(x_{1}+2x_{2})^{2}-x_{3} ^{2}-1=0  $

My calculations:

*Matrix:*

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}   $

$c=1$

Eigenvalues:
$\lambda _{1}=-1, \lambda _{2}=0,  \lambda _{3}=5 $   -> indefinit

How do I find area for these two and how can I make sketch of them?

Comment: What is a 2-order (or second order ?) area ? It reminds me of nothing... ? Could you explain a little more the context of your study ?

Comment: Sorry. I translated that from another language. I mean on hyperbola, ellipse and so on.

Comment: The common name for hyperbola, ellipse... is "conic section(s)" ; on the algebraic side, use "quadratic polynomials in variables $x,y$". Please modify your title and text by using these terms.

Comment: Hello, can I have your email id to contact you. I have few questions.

Comment: @Amar Sure. Write your email, I will contact you.

Comment: John.sr@yahoo.com

Comment: @Amar I sent you email.

Comment: I didn't get your mail.

Comment: @Amar anamatijanovic@outlook.com

Comment: gmail.com or facebook?

Comment: not facebook, just normal email

Comment: john.sr26@outlook.com please contact me there.

Comment: @Amar I sent email again.